# Modeling Infection Spread among Different Age Groups with Contact Matrix

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, matrix, systems-biology

In this code, we divided the population into children, adults, and old people.

1. The probability of infection per contact, $b$, is 5 % for people of all ages
2. The total population size is 1 million, and children make up 20 % of this population. 15 % of the population are elderly.
3. The population has not been exposed to the infection before.

The contacts between our 3 age groups can be summarised in a contact matrix, where 1 represents children, 2 represents adults and 3 represents the elderly. In this example, the average daily number of contacts between the different age groups in the contact matrix are :

Now my question is how could I write the following code using the above table? So that my code is not so long. As you can see, I've written 3 forces of infection and 3 systems of differential equations

$$\begin {pmatrix}
7 & 5 & 1 \\
2 & 9 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 2
\end {pmatrix}$$

I have modeled a vaccine with an all-or-nothing protective effect, which is 100 % effective in children and adults, but only 50 % effective in the elderly. There are 250, 000 vaccine doses available for the entire population. Since the infection causes more severe disease in the elderly, your task is to model which age group to prioritize for vaccination in order to minimize infection in the elderly.

***Now my question is how could I write the following code using the above table? So that my code is not so long. As you can see, I've written 3 forces of infection and 3 systems of differential equations.***

````
(*Recovery rate*)
\[Gamma] = 1/5;
(*the probability of infection per contact*)
b = 0.05;


(*daily number of contacts that children make with each other*)
c11 = 7;
(*daily number of contacts that children make with adults*)
c12 = 5;
(*daily number of contacts that children make with the elderly*)
c13 = 1;
(*daily number of contacts that adults make with children*)
c21 = 2;
(*daily number of contacts that adults make with each other*)
c22 = 9;
(*daily number of contacts that adults make with the elderly*)
c23 = 1;
(*daily number of contacts that elderly people make with children*)
c31 = 1;
(*daily number of contacts that elderly people make with adults*)
c32 = 3;
(*daily number of contacts that elderly people make with each other*)
c33 = 2;

(*Total Population Size*)
n = 1000000;
(*the population of children susceptible*)
n1 = 0.2*n
(*the population of adult susceptible*)
n2 = n - n1 - n3
(*the population of adult susceptible*)
n3 = 0.15*n

(*period of time in days*)
tmax = 90;

(*Force of infection acting on susceptible children:*)
\[Lambda]1[t_] := b*c11* i1[t]/n1 + b*c12*i2[t]/n2 + b*c13*i3[t]/n3;
(*Force of infection acting on susceptible adults:*)
\[Lambda]2[t_] := b*c21* i1[t]/n1 + b*c22*i2[t]/n2 + b*c23*i3[t]/n3;
(*Force of infection acting on susceptible elderly people:*)
\[Lambda]3[t_] := b*c31* i1[t]/n1 + b*c32*i2[t]/n2 + b*c33*i3[t]/n3;


(*vaccine coverage in children*)
vaccCov1 = 0;
(*vaccine coverage in adults*)
vaccCov2 = 0;
(*vaccine coverage in the elderly*)
vaccCov3 = 1;
(*vaccine efficacy in the elderly (100% in the other age groups)*)
vaccEff = 0.5;

p1 = vaccCov1;
p2 = vaccCov2;
p3 = vaccCov3*vaccEff;

(*Define the system of differential equations*)
(*Rate of change in children:*)
eqns1 = {
   s1'[t] == -\[Lambda]1[t]* s1[t],
   i1'[t] == \[Lambda]1 [t]* s1[t] - \[Gamma]* i1[t],
   r1'[t] == \[Gamma] *i1[t],
   s1[0] == n1 - p1*n1,
   i1[0] == 1,
   r1[0] == p1*n1};

(*Rate of change in adults:*)
eqns2 = {
   s2'[t] == -\[Lambda]2[t]* s2[t],
   i2'[t] == \[Lambda]2 [t]* s2[t] - \[Gamma]* i2[t],
   r2'[t] == \[Gamma] *i2[t],
   s2[0] == n2 - p2*n2,
   i2[0] == 0,
   r2[0] == p2*n2};

(*Rate of change in elderly:*)
eqns3 = {
   s3'[t] == -\[Lambda]3[t]* s3[t],
   i3'[t] == \[Lambda]3 [t]* s3[t] - \[Gamma]* i3[t],
   r3'[t] == \[Gamma] *i3[t],
   s3[0] == n3 - p3*n3,
   i3[0] == 0,
   r3[0] == p3*n3};

(*Solve the system*)
sol = NDSolve[{eqns1, eqns2, eqns3}, {s1, i1, r1, s2, i2, r2, s3, i3, 
    r3}, {t, 0, tmax}];




Plot[Evaluate[{s1[t], i1[t], r1[t], s2[t], i2[t], r2[t], s3[t], i3[t],
     r3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"S1", "I1", "R1", "S2", "I2", "R2", "S3", "I3", 
   "R3"}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Green}, {Dashed, 
    Red}, {Dashed, Blue}, {Dashed, Green}, {Thick, Dotted, 
    Red}, {Thick, Dotted, Blue}, {Thick, Dotted, Green}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]

```
````

Comment: It looks like you did write the code.  What's the problem?  Is it a Mathematica problem or a modeling problem?

Comment: @ChrisK I would like to define the age-specific contact pattern as a matrix. When calculating the force of infection, we multiply the contact matrix with the vector of the proportion of infected people for each age group, giving us 3 age-specific forces of infection stored in the $\lambda$ vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really enjoy your epidemic series :-) It is always better to decouple the weedy details of a specific model from the key question. Key question should be purified to bare minimum. Perhaps helpful, -- there is matrix format for `NDSolve`, this is how it works:

```
A=RandomReal[{0,1},{5,5}];
fs=NDSolveValue[{x'[t]==A.x[t],x[0]==IdentityMatrix[5]},x,{t,0,1}]
```

Compare to the exact solution:

```
LogPlot[Norm[Flatten[fs[t] - MatrixExp[A t]]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Hopefully this format is applicable to your model. Let me know if you see that it is not. Exact doc reference: [NDSolveValue >> Scope >> ODEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html)